# previous and next post buttons by category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, I show the previous and next post buttons for the category. However, if a post has more than one category, how do I determine from which category the user clicked on that post? From which category the user clicked on that post, the previous and next buttons should be based on the category he came from. In all my attempts, the previous and next post buttons are created based on the primary category and I don't want that.

I need it for a different project, is there a method?